# Is the Pinterest ads API open to all developers yet?

Tags: pinterest, ads-api

My company has several customers interested in integrating our marketing software with Pinterest. I've seen lots of articles about Pinterest's ads API, but the closest I've seen to it being "live" is an [article](https://business.pinterest.com/en/marketing-developer-partners) announcing their marketing development partners.

Is the Pinterest ads API publicly available, and if so, do I get access when I sign up as a regular Pinterest developer (and where are the docs)? If not, is there any notice announcing when it will be?

Comment: I've not looked into it myself, but according to this article (http://adexchanger.com/social-media/pinterest-pulls-the-trigger-on-its-ads-api/), as of June API keys are still invite-only.

Comment: I've seen that article too, but I haven't found anything more recent regarding when (or if) they plan to change that. Thanks though!